# How do make the first option in my drop down menu have no value?

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu that sends emails to different departments in a company based on user selection. I need the first option in the menu, the "Select Department", to have no value, so users cannot select it, they must choose a department.

Here is my PHP:

```
// config
$emailAddresses = array(

'Select Department'=>'',
'Service Department'=>'blahblah1@gmail.com',
'Sales Department'=>'blahblah2@gmail.com',
'Parts Department'=>'blahblah3@gmail.com',
'Customer Service Department'=>'blahblah4@gmail.com',
'Bids Department'=>'blahblah5@gmail.com'

 // etc etc
 );
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
<label for='destemail' >Select department you're trying to reach: <font style="color:#f93;  margin-left:-2px; ">*</font></label></br>
<select name="destemail" id="destemail">
<?php foreach ($emailAddresses as $name => $email) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name); ?>">
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name) ; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
<span id='contactus_destemail_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
```

Help much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Could you try this: ''=>'*option I want to have no value*', as a first array element?

Comment: If you want to prevent them from selecting it, you have to use validation. Setting it to no value won't do that.

Comment: How are you transforming this array into a select box? Are you using a framework or some custom code? If the latter, please post the code.

Comment: I would use some JS on the form page itself that won't allow it to be submitted unless that field is correctly selected.

Comment: The problem is, I'm unsure how to write that code and apply it to what I have. I already have JS that stops people from submitting certain forms without filling them out correctly, but in this case, it won't stop the user from sending this if they choose the first "Select Department" option, because the code is seeing it as the user HAS chosen a department. I need for this option to not be selectable. @Fluffeh

Comment: @KateG You write a custom function that checks the fields after a change. In your case, you would check whether the drop-down was on the "Make a selection" value - and if so, disable the submit button. So if they make a selection, it is enabled, but if they change it back to the invalid value, the submit button is again disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using ($emailAddresses as $name => $email) so that the $name is both the label and the value in your select. This is your problem.... I think you mean to use the $email as the value and the $name as the option label (value visible to the user). if this is correct, your array as it is in the question currently should work with those changes.

```
$emailAddresses = array(

   'Select Department'=>'',
   'Service Department'=>'blahblah1@gmail.com',
   'Sales Department'=>'blahblah2@gmail.com',
   'Parts Department'=>'blahblah3@gmail.com',
   'Customer Service Department'=>'blahblah4@gmail.com',
   'Bids Department'=>'blahblah5@gmail.com'

    // the departments become the $name in your foreach
    // the email addresses become the $email
 );
```

....

```
<div class='container'>
  <label for='destemail' >Select department you're trying to reach: 
  <font style="color:#f93;  margin-left:-2px; ">*</font></label></br>
  <select name="destemail" id="destemail">
   <?php foreach ($emailAddresses as $name => $email) { ?>  

              <!--  The reason it wouldn't work is because you had the following line: -->
              <!--    <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name); ?>">          -->

              <!--    But it needs to be this for any of that to work... -->
              <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($email); ?>">
              <?php echo htmlspecialchars($name) ; ?></option> 
   <?php } ?>
  </select>
<span id='contactus_destemail_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
```

---

put this in a file and run it to see how everything works and should be set up.  You are allowing `destemail` to have a blank value so it is allowed to post with one... I think that might be the problem you're seeing.  Test this page out.  Submit the form with "Select Department" and then some of the other options to see if that is your desired behavior.

```
<?php

// replace with the name of the current filename 
$file_name = "this_page.php";

if (!empty($_POST)) 
{
   print "<pre>".print_r($_POST,true)."</pre>"; 
}
else 
{
   print "<pre>\$_POST is empty</pre>";
}

$emailAddresses = array( 
   'Select Department'=>'',
   'Service Department'=>'Service@gmail.com',
   'Sales Department'=>'Sales@gmail.com',
   'Parts Department'=>'Parts@gmail.com',
   'Customer Service Department'=>'CustomerService@gmail.com',
   'Bids Department'=>'Bids@gmail.com' 
); 

?>

<br/><br/><br/>
<form action="<?php echo $file_name ?>" method="post">
   <div class='container'>
     <label for='destemail' >Select department you're trying to reach: 
     <font style="color:#f93;  margin-left:-2px; ">*</font></label></br>
     <select name="destemail" id="destemail">
      <?php foreach ($emailAddresses as $name => $email) { ?>   
                 <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($email); ?>">
                 <?php echo htmlspecialchars($name) ; ?></option> 
      <?php } ?>
     </select>
   <span id='contactus_destemail_errorloc' class='error'></span> 
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The error code now shows up, but it shows up even when I select a department and press submit. Here is the error code in my php: 
        `//destemail validaions

        if(empty($_POST['destemail']))
                      {
                      $this->add_error("Please select a department.");
                      $ret = false;
                      }`                                                          Any idea what's going on? @gloomy.penguin

Comment: so... after you submit the form, you're not receiving the `$_POST` value for that select (`destmail`)?  do you get other information through `$_POST` for that form (is everything blank or just that item)?  is the form method set to post (and not get)?  is the select between the `<form>` and `</form>` tags?  I might need to see the surrounding form and elements to help troubleshoot if those suggestions don't help.

Answer (score 0):

You should output an `<option>` with an empty `value` attribute. For example, you could use this HTML (note the `<option` on the fourth line):

```
<div class='container'>
    <label for='destemail'>Select department you're trying to reach: <font style="color:#f93;  margin-left:-2px; ">*</font></label></br>
    <select name="destemail" id="destemail">
        <option value="">Select Department</option>
        <?php foreach ($emailAddresses as $name => $email) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name); ?>">
                <?php echo htmlspecialchars($name) ; ?>
            </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <span id='contactus_destemail_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
```